# Python prepared statement freeze when i call execute (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm curious to know why on Windows 10. This statement freezes python console entirely:

```
sql = """ select distinct u.handle, u.speed from gtp_user u where u.handle=? """
cursor.execute(sql, 'test')
```

and on the other hand, the following works just fine:

```
sql = """ select distinct u.handle, u.speed from gtp_user u where u.handle='test' """
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: no error, just freezes the runtime... control+z wont work to stop the python process either

Comment: Try `cursor.execute(sql, ('test',))`

Comment: What is `cursor`? Are you using a database access library (e.g. [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) from the standard library)? If so, which one? And if that library supports several database management systems (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, sqlite, PostgreSQL), which one are you accessing?

Comment: pyodbc
PostgreSQL database

    DBconn = pyodbc.connect(...)
    cursor = DBconn.cursor()

Answer (score 1):

When I run a modification of your sample code, I get the following

```
>>> db.execute('SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE id = ?', 'test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

The [api docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) show that this has to be either an iterable or a dictionary:

```
>>> db.execute('SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE id = ?', ('test',))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1264110>
>>> db.execute('SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE id = :id', {'id': 'test'})
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x12b6c70>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, these gave the same result. Python console freezes with no output